# unset session does not work well PHP

Tags: php

I want to unset username n the cart when logout button is click.
if I want to put, if logout is click, then the session will unset, how should i do it?

my codes works
however, when I click on login again,
the login information is not store in the sessions.
It keep ask my to login again, instead of carry on the usual flow.
May I know what's wrong?

here is my code 
cart.php

```
$logout = "allproducts.php";

if(isset($logout))
{
    unset($_SESSION['supermarketcart']);
    unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
}

?>
```

---

```
<?php 

          if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']) == NULL) 
          { 
              echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a> " ;

          } 
          else 
          { 
              echo " <a href='$logout'>Logout</a> "; 
          }
      ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "index.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php?fail=1";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM user_data WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try taking out `session_start();` from the if condition.

Comment: In `cart.php`, `isset($logout)` will always be true because you assign the variable on the previous line. I don't understand why you're checking that variable.

Comment: @Barmar this is because, if i click logout, i want to unset the variable

Comment: @Rikesh it can't work.

Comment: What does that variable have to do with clicking logout? It's just a string that you assign unconditionally. That's why your variables are always being unset.

Comment: @Barmar how can i do to improve it?

Comment: when a user logouts send a get message to the server and unset the session

Comment: You should check something like `$_POST['logout']`.

Answer (score 0):

As what Barmar said, you're having an always-true condition that always unset your sections. What you should do instead, is put a static address for logout page with a GET variable passing through. Let's make it `$_GET['logout']` and assign the value of 1

```
   <?php 
      if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']) == NULL) 
      { 
          echo "<a href='login.php'>Login</a> " ;

      } 
      else 
      { 
          echo " <a href='allproducts.php?logout=1'>Logout</a> "; 
      }
  ?>
```

Then check the `GET variable` instead of the always-exists `$logout`

```
if($_GET['logout']==1)
{
    unset($_SESSION['supermarketcart']);
    unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
}
```